# Windows Server 2003 SP2 NIC doesn't work

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003

Windows Server 2003 SP2 virtual machine inside vCenter4. Network setup is a common DMZ:

10.0.0.x - Firewall - 192.168.1.x

There are a bunch of Windows Server 2003 in the 192 network, but today we noticed that one of them was not accessible. It's like any network service isn't working. I can't ping, can't use RDP, HTTP... That server has Wireshark installed (I wonder why..), and I noticed the only traffic is outgoing broadcast traffic, so the problem seems to be like if the network card wasn't working properly.

According to the users of that server, it started to fail on Friday. Friday a pair of coworkers were doing some migration and powered off a few machines. Also, Friday I changed firewall setup.

I have checked and rechecked and it's not firewall problem, as even loading previous config isn't working. Also, all of the other servers use the same services and they are working  without any problems, the rules are basically a copy&paste changing the port.

Microsoft has many acknowledged issues of this version after installing SP2, but I have checked all of them and no one worked.The SP2 wasn't installed recently either, so I don't think that  this is going to be my problem.

I tried to remove NIC and reinstall VMWare Tools, but still the network activity is null.

Comment: Both those things are ancient, and were overdue for an upgrade 5 years ago.  Good thing you have an excuse now.

Comment: @HopelessN00b trust me, they are not going to upgrade anytime soon. I've been digging a little more and I think the problem is the IPSec block mode issue, but neither following Microsoft steps nor disabling IPSec at all fix it.

Comment: Well, their options are to upgrade to something current that's supportable, or tolerate the problems that come from running old, unsupportable crap on the cheap.  If they're not willing to upgrade, they've made their decision, and the best thing you can do is help them understand the consequences of that decision.  (Specifically, here, you're going to waste a lot of time, probably not be able to fix it, and the people who rely on this server aren't going to be able to do whatever it is this server lets them do.)  Best of luck and all, but that's really what your situation boils down to.

Answer (score 0):

well... problem solved. It turned out that after the migration done by my coworkers, this virtual server wasn't allocated in the right blade, and that affected the network services according to whoever designed the infrastructure.